# RViz and interactive markers: Why does not pose automatically updated?

Tags: ros, pose, rviz, update, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

When an interactive marker's pose is changed using a control (for instance the 6-DoF control provided in **basic_controls**), why does the field **int_marker.pose** is not filled why the new value automatically?

I spent a long time debugging my node when I realized that I had to update it myself with such a callback function for instance:

```
void processFeedback(const visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerFeedbackConstPtr &feedback)
{
switch (feedback->event_type) {
    case visualization_msgs::InteractiveMarkerFeedback::POSE_UPDATE:
        int_marker.pose = feedback->pose; // MANDATORY??
        server->insert(int_marker, &processFeedback);
        server->applyChanges();
        break;
}
```

Even if the pose is not updated, the display is correct and my object moves when I control it with the interactive marker, so where are stored its coordinates?

Many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124316/rviz-and-interactive-markers:-why-does-not-pose-automatically-updated?/) by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 454 on 2014-01-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, so, in fact, when an interactive marker is inserted to the server, it creates a copy of it instead of referencing it. So we have two living copies of the interactive marker: the original InteractiveMarker declared, and the one of the server than we can access through `server->get("name", out_im)` (which gives back A COPY of the marker within the server).

For this specific issue, the version on the server is updated to the current pose every time, but not the other one that we have to update manually. I don't know what justifies this implementation but it's really annoying, we have to synchronize both versions all the time if we want to modify the interactive marker in real time. Getting the version of the server, modifying it and then pushing again... not very clean :s

---

Originally posted by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) with karma: 454 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0